# No printer icon in Ubuntu 14.04 system settings

Tags: printing, 14.04, icons

When I Upgraded from 12.04 I had a problem booting till I changed `RO` to `RW` in boot files. But my current problem is that I cannot see a printer icon in system settings, and How do I fix it.

Answer (score 5):

The `Printers` entry into Unity is provided by file `/usr/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop`.

Its content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Printers
Comment=Configure printers
Exec=system-config-printer
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=printer
StartupNotify=true
NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=system-config-printer
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;System;Printing;
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=printing
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=printing
Keywords=Printer;Queue;Print;Paper;Ink;Toner;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Permissions of the file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 471 Mar 14 13:19 system-config-printer.desktop
```

And when I asked about this file in packages (`dpkg -S system-config-printer.desktop`) I got as result:

```
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/system-config-printer-gnome:system-config-printer.desktop
system-config-printer-gnome: /usr/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop
```

And searching by `system-config-printer` at Synaptic:

[image: Screen capture of Synaptic]

So, maybe if you can check if you have the above packages installed, file in place, correct content/permissions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Even how many weeks after the release of 14.04, there is no update available for this ugly bug.

The solution is to install the `printer-indicator` for Ubuntu 14.10
Just choose your version and download it here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/indicator-printers/0.1.7+14.10.20140527-0ubuntu1

and install by:

```
sudo dpkg -i indicator-printers_0.1.7+14.10.20140527-0ubuntu1*.deb
```

Logout/Login and the printer indicator is back like before.

Answer (score 1):

I did all checks suggested by Rael. I found out in the Synaptics that the system-config-printer-gnome was not the same version as the two other file. I marked it up for upgrade and applied the upgrade. Bingo, the printer icon is now in the Settings screen.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I have removed the cups service by accident, you can reinstall it by `sudo apt-get install cups` and the printer setting icon appear again in the system settings panel, or if you cups service exists, you may try just install `sudo apt install   system-config-printer-gnome`. Good luck!

Comment: The latter doesn't help - it is already installed on this 14.04 system.

Comment: I had the same issue on 16.04 and sudo apt install system-config-printer-gnome fixed it.